# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<String> in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>           Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator to Iterable
>
> at com.spark.wordcount.lession1.WordCount2.main(WordCount2.java:26)

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("cust data").setMaster("local[*]");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("C:\\\\Users\\\\dell\\\\Desktop\\\\simple_text_file.txt");
     JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s)).iterator());

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> output = counts.collect();
        for (Tuple2<?,?> tuple : output) {
          System.out.println(tuple._1() + ": " + tuple._2());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing incompatible versions of Spark / code:

- In Spark 2.x `FlatMapFunction.call` [is `java.util.Iterator<R> call(T t)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html#call-T-)
- In Spark 1.x `FlatMapFunction.call` [is `Iterable<R> call(T t)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html).

You should either upgrade Spark dependency to 2.x and keep your current code or use `FlatMapFunction` [compatible with 1.x branch](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a233fac0b8bf8229d938a24f2ede2d9d8861c284/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java#L47-L52):

```
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
    return Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should already be visible in your (Eclipse?) IDE by the red squiqly lines *and* the warning that your source contains errors before you actually execute the program. Eclipse nicely lets you run anyway and includes code that will throw the 'Unresolved compilation problem' if you hit the code that has a problem.

The exception indicates that you are passing an `Iterator<>` while the calling method is expecting an `Iteratable<>`, that is an object that implements that interface and has a method `iterator()` which returns an `Iterator`.

Comment: ,Hi I am using same code as it is Spark github code as https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java,   but still getting error, I tried as u suggested but not resolved yet.